# PHP Process ID and unique

Tags: php

I want to run a php script on background and store its PID on database. So that I can check if the particular script running or not (later).

We can use `getmypid` to get current PID.

But as per the PHP manual

> Process IDs are not unique, thus they are a weak entropy source. We
>   recommend against relying on pids in security-dependent contexts.

...and I cannot rely on PID.

My second idea is to store the process created time to the database.

How can I get the current script created time? And later how can I compare with tasklist to check whether the particular script is running or not?

I am running on a shared host, windows/linux environment.

Comment: the comment about PID in a security related context is refering to "source of entropy" and situations like `srand(getmypid());`. you seem  to need some kind of process-monitoring mechanism like daemontools, perp, minit and the like: most of these mechanism fork-away a childprocess and watch filedescriptors and signals to see if the child is still alive. with your idea you have to fight against timing issues, permissions etc (to find out if the process currently having PID you stored in the DB is actually the same process).

Comment: http://kr.github.io/beanstalkd/ (it's a job-queue) btw uses something neat: the process who has taken a given job has to report back to the queue that it still is alive and working on the task. you could implement something similar in php as well: if the process itself does not report back in time with a given identifier you can consider that task as beeing interrupted / failed etc. watching signals / filedescriptors of spawned / forked child-processes is still easier imho.

Comment: might be useful: https://github.com/CHH/kue - `A minimalistic, generic and framework independent interface to job queues`

Comment: @akira Thanks alot .. let me check ..

Answer (score 4):

From [php.net/getmypid](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getmypid.php#93753)

with little modification to disable non cli access.

script can be executed using `/usr/bin/php script.php`.

Additionally use `nohup /usr/bin/php script.php > nohup.out &` to launch a [nohup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup) process in background.

```
#!/usr/bin/php 
<?php 

if ( PHP_SAPI !== 'cli' ) {
    die( "Cmd line access only!\n" );
}

define( 'LOCK_FILE', "/var/run/".basename( $argv[0], ".php" ).".lock" );  // can also use /tmp
if( isLocked() ) die( "Already running.\n" ); 

# The rest of your script goes here.... 
echo "Hello world!\n"; 
sleep(30); 

unlink( LOCK_FILE ); 
exit(0); 

function isLocked() 
{ 
    # If lock file exists, check if stale.  If exists and is not stale, return TRUE 
    # Else, create lock file and return FALSE. 

    if( file_exists( LOCK_FILE ) ) 
    { 
        # check if it's stale 
        $lockingPID = trim( file_get_contents( LOCK_FILE ) ); 

       # Get all active PIDs. 
        $pids = explode( "\n", trim( `ps -e | awk '{print $1}'` ) ); 

        # If PID is still active, return true 
        if( in_array( $lockingPID, $pids ) )  return true; 

        # Lock-file is stale, so kill it.  Then move on to re-creating it. 
        echo "Removing stale lock file.\n"; 
        unlink( LOCK_FILE ); 
    } 

    file_put_contents( LOCK_FILE, getmypid() . "\n" ); 
    return false; 

} 
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on your level of access to target machine. You can use PHP CLI, store PIDs (they are unique to particular point in time, so you won't have 2 processes with same PIDs running) and grep them in the output of `ps -ax` to check if they are running. If not - delete them from database, so that you won't have problem with the same PID occuring.

Comment: Not instantly. You will be able to mark it as finished in DB. Include date/time too to distinguish.

Answer (score 0):

You can try use the PID with another id, for example:

if you have a zipping job that uses a file id = 327, try to store {PID}327, and with this check if this particular job still running.

Even if the PID get reused, you will not have that PID with id 327 stored, or if you restart the zipping process with this particular id 327, probabily the PID will change.

But, to avoid get the same PID with this id 327, you'll have to check your database before, and then add a counter at the end of the composed id, like {PID}327_1.

Hope this can help you.